# how to using "For" instead of "each" function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

Today i'm very stack with a Work and jQ. I was get a morning for it but i can't resolve it :(. 
My Work here:

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="test">a</p>
    <div>
        <p class="test">a</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In normal, i can using jQ with each function `for` select all `<p class="test">a</p>` EX:

```
$(".test").each(function() {
    $(this).text('a');
});
```

But i hear everyone talk that, `for` function get a less timeload than `each` function. Now i want using `for` instead of `each`.. but i don't know how to write code jQ in this case.

Somebody can help me!. thankyou!

Comment: Why do you want less time load? Is it a very consuming operation? The rule for javascript is that if its not lagging, and there arent an excessive amount of errors, its good code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it unless you were iterating through hundreds of them.

`for` loop is usually used with normal DOM (aka without jQuery) traversing, like...

```
var elements = document.getElementById('something').getElementsByTagName('a');

var elementsLength = elements.length;

for (var i = 0; i < elementsLength; i++) {

    elements[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

Caching of `elementsLength` is a good idea so it is not calculated every iteration. Thanks to [CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms) for this suggestion in the comments.

Just adapt that for your jQuery object if you wanted to do it with jQuery.

Replace `elements` variable with your jQuery collection, like `$('#something a')`. I think you may need to rewrap the object if you need to do any more jQuery stuff with it.

Comment: last time I checked getElementById returned one html element, which hadn't had any methods like getElementsByTagName. That is only what document had. Long story short I don't think it's possible to chain methods like that with native javascript methods

Comment: His code is correct.  You may use any DOM element as context to descend with a getElementsByTagName or getElementsByClassName like that.

Comment: @alex: The condition of your loop should be `i < elements.length` since `elements[elements.length]` will be `undefined` (they are 0-based) otherwise you'll get a `TypeError` at the last iteration, also when working with HTMLCollections is a good idea to *cache* the value of `length` property, because accessing that value on each iteration is expensive, since HTMLCollections are ["live"](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/glossary.html#dt-live). E.g. `for(var i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; i++)`

Comment: yea, all guys answer is right. I think code of every is similar. also this is right code :). thankyou all :)

Comment: @CMS I knew cacheing the length was a good idea, but wasn't sure if adding it would cloud the most important thing - the actual traversal. Still, I included it :)

Answer (score 5):

One thing to watch out for is that using an ordinal accessor on the result of a jQuery selection will return a native DomElement.  If you want to use jQuery methods on them, you have to re-wrap them:

```
var testElements = $('.test');

for (var i = 0; i < testElements.length; i++) {
  // Using $() to re-wrap the element.
  $(testElements[i]).text('a');
}
```

I'd second what others have said though.  Unless you're dealing with many elements, this is premature optimization.  Re-wrapping the elements to use the .text() method may even bring it back to no gain at all.

Comment: +1 for "Re-wrapping the elements to use the .text() method may even bring it back to no gain at all.". I don't have any benchmarks, but it sounds cumbersome to rewrap every iteration.

Comment: Re-wrapping is the `$(element)` step within the loop. That's necessary if you still want to be able to use jQuery's methods on each element, but it comes at a performance cost for each iteration (as jQuery much construct a new jQuery object to wrap that element with its extended functionality).

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the obvious solution?

```
var nodes = $(".test");
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{
    var node = nodes[i];
}
```

Comment: The for block is not a closure, so you would be technically redefining the same variable on each loop. Not sure, but I think that throws an error.

Comment: Variable declarations are "hoisted" to the top, so what it actually looks like is this: `var nodes, node; nodes = $('.test'); for (...) { node = nodes[i]; }`

Comment: why would I reference same element. nodes is a array of html elements. i-th element in this collection is one of found elements with class test. I don't see a problem here

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/javascript-for-loop-vs-jquery-each.html) shows that `each()` has no significant performance penalty until you get into the hundreds of thousands of looped-over items.

Comment: That's commendable, but this would be a trivial performance gain at the cost of decreased code clarity and maintainability.  I'd bet there are bigger performance hogs elsewhere.  Like `Something.length` in a `for` loop maybe?  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('.test').length; i++){
    var element = $('.test').eq(i);
}
```